# The primary or stateless instance for the partition has an invalid address on Secondary Replica

Tags: c#, partition, azure-service-fabric

I am trying to create a proxy on a random secondary replica by passing in the TargetReplicaSelector.RandomSecondaryReplica to ServiceProxy.Create call. When I do that, I get the invalid address error. If I take that out, I have no issues at all.

This is what my create Listener looks like:

```
return new List<ServiceReplicaListener>
        {
            new ServiceReplicaListener(this.CreateServiceRemotingListener)
        };
```

So I don't see anything wrong there. What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's an additional parameter on ServiceReplicaListener that instructs it to open your listener on secondary replicas. It's false by default.

```
return new List<ServiceReplicaListener>
{
    new ServiceReplicaListener(this.CreateServiceRemotingListener, listenOnSecondary: true)
};
```

Comment: Boom. Thanks for the help!